# getting SQL Error (1452): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (Unknown error code)

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, ndbcluster

I am getting error with MySQL NDB Cluster 7.3.5 as described below:

I have two tables:

-User Profiles

-User Services

User services is a child table which contains foreign key constraint (user_profile_id).

```
insert into user_services (address_type, apn_id, ggsn_id, ip_address, user_profile_id, vpn_id, id) values ('DYNAMIC', 2, 'GGSN01', null, 250, 3, 102);
/* SQL Error (1452): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (Unknown error code) */
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 0 of 1 query: 0.000 sec. */
```

The strange thing here is that the parent table User Profiles has the entry with Id 250, but still I am getting error when inserting a row using 250 as user_profile_id.

I have checked the log files for data nodes(ndb_id_out.log) and API node(mysqld.id.err) but no luck!

I don't know where to check the logs for these kind of errors.

DDL of Schemas are as described below:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_services` (
  `id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `apn_id` decimal(22,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ggsn_id` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `vpn_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `user_profile_id` decimal(22,0) NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_type` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_ser_profile` (`user_profile_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ser_profile` FOREIGN KEY (`user_profile_id`) REFERENCES `user_profiles` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `user_profiles` (
    `id` DECIMAL(22,0) NOT NULL,
    `group_id` DECIMAL(22,0) NOT NULL,
    `imsi` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `username` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `password` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_bin',
    `last_modified` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `unique_username` (`username`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER;
```

can you help me on this ?

Comment: Post the SHOW CREATE TABLE results, please.

Comment: @AlainCollins updated the question. pls let me know if you need further information.